# Box2D pixels to meters , LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am confused . what shall I set the orthographic camera viewport in libGDX when I use box2d , in one tutorial I saw that he divided his viewport numbers to 32  because 1meter =32 pixel , but I think it will make the images to be displayed by lower quality , so can anybody explain me what viewport shall I set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to find the needed ratio between Texture size and meters. I would probably use 100px:1m.  Then, when you are setting the fixture sizes, multiply the texture size with the ratio.

Try something like this:

```
//RATIO
private float ratio = 1/100;

// TEXTURE
private Texture texture = new Texture(YOUR TEXTURE PATH);

private float fixtureHeight = texture.getHeight() * ratio;
```

So now, if your player will be 200px heigh, then ,in box2d, it will be 2 meters high.